# Router issues with Vertx

Tags: java, eclipse, routes, vert.x

Good morning, 
I begin with Vertx for java and I want to create the route example so I copy past the lines but it seems there is something wrong in Router.router(vertex) :

> - The type io.vertx.rxjava.core.Vertx cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
>      required .class files
>
>   - The method router(Vertx) from the type Router refers to the missing type Vertx

Here is my code :

```
import io.vertx.core.*;
import io.vertx.rxjava.ext.web.*;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpHeaders;

public class Test extends AbstractVerticle{

@Override
public void start() throws Exception {

    Vertx vertx=Vertx.vertx();
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);

    Route route1 = router.route("localhost:8080/Orsys/").handler(routingContext -> {

          HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
          response.setChunked(true);

          response.write("Orsys\n");

          routingContext.vertx().setTimer(5000, tid -> routingContext.next());
        });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First the `Vertx` instance in the `io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle` class refers to `io.vertx.core.Vertx`, not `io.vertx.rxjava.core.Vertx`. So you are supposed to import `io.vertx.ext.web.Router` rather than `io.vertx.rxjava.ext.web.Router`, or it won't match.

Second, the `Route#route` method is not a static method so first you need to create a Router instance:

```
Router router = Router.router(vertx);
```

And then invoke the route method:

```
router.route("/Test1").handler(routingContext -> {
            HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
            response.setChunked(true);
            response.write("Test1 \n");

            routingContext.vertx().setTimer(1000, tid ->  routingContext.next());
        });
```

Notice that the `route` method **does not** accept the absolute URL so you needn't pass the absolute URL. Directly pass the `/Test1` URL path and the host and port can be configured when createHttpServer.

Another notice is that if you want to write bytes directly to response, you should add `response.setChunked(true)` or an exception would be thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must set the Content-Length header to be the total size of the message body BEFORE sending any data if you are not using HTTP chunked encoding.
```

Or this is better(always wnd with `end`):

```
router.route("/Test1").handler(routingContext -> {
            HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
            response.putHeader("content-type", "text/html");
            response.end("<h1>Test1</h1>");
        });
```

By now you have established a simple route, so next step is create a HttpServer:

```
vertx.createHttpServer()
                .requestHandler(router::accept)
                .listen(8080, "127.0.0.1", res -> {
                    if (res.failed())
                        res.cause().printStackTrace();
                });
```

Well, the port and host can be passed to the `listen` method.

So this is the changed correct code:

```
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServerResponse;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;

public class TestVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {
        Router router = Router.router(vertx);

        router.route("/Test1").handler(routingContext -> {
            HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
            response.setChunked(true);
            response.write("Test1 \n");

            routingContext.vertx().setTimer(1000, tid ->  routingContext.next());
        });

        vertx.createHttpServer()
                .requestHandler(router::accept)
                .listen(8080, "127.0.0.1", res -> {
                    if (res.succeeded())
                        startFuture.complete();
                    else
                        startFuture.fail(res.cause());
                });
    }
}
```

Run this by deploy the verticle:

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        TestVerticle verticle = new TestVerticle();

        vertx.deployVerticle(verticle, res -> {
            if (res.failed())
                res.cause().printStackTrace();
        });
    }
}
```

So this is only a simple example. And if you want to build a RESTful Service, this article might help: [Some Rest with Vert.x](http://vertx.io/blog/some-rest-with-vert-x/)

And here is my example of a RESTful Service using Vert.x Web, which may also help:https://github.com/sczyh30/todo-backend-vert.x

I hope these can help you :)

Comment: Thank you @sczyh30 for your explications, very helpful :) I tried to rebuild my code using Gradle (even if I'm not familiar with it, but it's good to discover new things) But it seems it doesn't run as normal project I mean go to run configuration and set mine, correct me if I'm mistaken. 
Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Eric Zhao's answer is great. But I want to add something.

I faced to the same issue with my Vert.x application. It first said `Cannot resolve symbol 'Router'`. So I import `io.vertx.ext.web.Router`. But my application didn't import it and said `Cannot resolve symbol 'web'` and also `Cannot resolve symbol 'Router'`.

I solved that issue by adding below dependency to my pom.xml .

`Maven`

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
 <artifactId>vertx-web</artifactId>
 <version>3.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

`Gradle`

```
dependencies {
 compile 'io.vertx:vertx-web:3.6.2'
}
```

Comment: I met the exact problem, had to add the `vertx-web` dependency